# godaddy cpanel user privileged issue

Tags: php

I uploaded some custom PHP code to GoDaddy CPanel, and I also created a database, and added a user to it, and assigned all privileges to them.

The site works perfectly but after some time round about half of a day the user permission from CPanel gets revoked automatically and the site displays an access denied error.

A simple question is why are the user's permissions being revoked automatically? is there any CPanel setting to change this?

Comment: That should not happen. You should report it to GoDaddy's support.

Comment: Ok thanku Enrico for your thoughts.